# Create an object to combine duplicate files

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and have following object where `key` is path of a file and `value` is *file name* and the *time* it was added. The files are duplicated and name are same i.e. **JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg** and **Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf**

```
{"/home/JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg": ["JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg", "2018-02-23T02:43:21"],

 "/Photos/JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg": ["JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg", "2018-02-23T02:43:42"],

 "/home/Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf": ["Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf", "2018-02-23T02:01:24"],

 "/Photos/Sample Album/Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf": ["Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf", "2018-02-23T02:01:56"]}
```

I want to create another object and combine the same name files basically to tell the user that the same file is stored at two different locations.

The expected output is:

```
{"JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg": ["/home/JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg", "2018-02-23T02:43:21"], ["/Photos/JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg", "2018-02-23T02:43:42"]}

{"Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf": ["/home/Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List", "2018-02-23T02:01:24"], ["/Photos/Sample Album/Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf", "2018-02-23T02:01:56"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your input**

```
var input = {"/home/JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg": ["JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg", "2018-02-23T02:43:21"],
 "/Photos/JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg": ["JackFusco_JasperGeminids.jpg", "2018-02-23T02:43:42"],

 "/home/Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf": ["Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf", "2018-02-23T02:01:24"],

 "/Photos/Sample Album/Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf": ["Goldman-Sachs-Suggested-Reading-List.pdf", "2018-02-23T02:01:56"]};
```

**Solution** (after having defined "input")

```
var result = {};
for (var key in input){
  if(!result.hasOwnProperty(input[key][0])) result[input[key][0]] = [];
  result[input[key][0]].push(key);
}
```

- First you initialize a new javascript object `result`
- Second, you check if `result` has already a property that matches your file name. If it doesn't you create such property, and initialize it as an array.
- Finally you push the keys of your object (file paths) to the corresponding array.

Comment: Thanks, does the job.